# How would look like the distribution of warmer and colder air molecules inside a spacestation with no gravity?

Tags: gravity, kinematics, temperature, density

How would look like the distribution of warmer and colder air molecules inside a spacestation with no gravity? Also how would look like the form of the fire when somebody lights up a piece of paper?

Comment: They actually lit a candle at the iss, you can google the video

Answer (score 1):

In a space station you'd think that since there is zero gravity, there'd be no pressure difference, so hot air would not rise (buoyant force is zero) as it would here on earth. Instead the warmer gas would just continue to diffuse uniformly in every direction from the heat source. The gas throughout will reach a constant temperature also due to thermal conduction.

Applying the same logic, a flame would appear more circular rather than form patterns that travel upward. For example, if the air was still, and you lit a candle, instead of having an oval shape with a point at the top, it would appear spherical.